# ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.IsInertial always returning false

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a windows phone app and I want to estimate the distance for element when user flicks on screen. The problem is `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs.IsInertial` is always returning false and I'm unable to detect the user flick.

This is my `ManipulationDelta` Event Handler

```
private void ItemList_ManipulationDelta(Object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double currPos = e.Position.X;
    var fwElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    Thickness margin = fwElement.Margin;
    margin.Left += (currPos - origin);
    if (margin.Left < marginLeft) margin.Left = marginLeft;
    fwElement.Margin = margin; 
    if (e.IsInertial)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("intertial");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have *Inertia* related `ManipulationModes` enabled for `e.IsInertial` to work.

For example,

`this.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia;`